How to make `Shift` sticky. So when I press `Shift` it shifts the first next letter or shifts the first next symbol (`'` -> `"`) NixOS

My use case for this is typeracer and general typing.


I tried NixOS Gnome sticky keys
and the first I click it before writing the quote first 2 letters get
capitalized and then it works normally, but then I click some other
modifier key and I need to turn it off and on, and it just does not suit my
use case.

Found this but i get an error:
Sticky shift key
[user@hostname:/etc/nixos]$ xkbset -sticky twokey
XKB not supported for display :0

[user@hostname:/etc/nixos]$ xkbset sticky twokey
XKB not supported for display :0

(Found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xkbset/+bug/215496) But it just does not work for me?
#!/usr/bin/env bash
setxkbmap -layout "us"
xkbset -sticky twokey

[user@hostname:/etc/nixos]$ ./sticky_shift.sh 
WARNING: Running setxkbmap against an Xwayland server

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36066855/17820864
Found this but for AutoHotKey and that is available for Windows and there seems to be an option for Linux but seems like the version is old.
I am running X11 but I am trying to go for Wayland if that can help. I will be happy if anything works like I requested.
NixOS 24.05

This works on wayland, for both the right and the left shift.
Add this to your /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
of course make sure to also install it
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    keyd
  ];

  services.keyd = {
    enable = true;
      keyboards = {
        default = {
          ids = [ "*" ];
          settings = {
            main = {
              shift = "oneshot(shift)";
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };

